# Elementary proof of the prime number theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The prime number theorem is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x} \left| \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) \right| = 0$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function.

We know that $\left| \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) \right| \leq x$ for all integers $x\geq 1$, and  since this grows in a certainly *nonlinear* way, we can write $\left| \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) \right| \leq x^{1-\delta}$ for every $x\geq 2$. For the purposes of our argument, it suffices to assume that $0<\delta<1$ is dependent on $x$.. Dividing throughout by $x$ we arrive at                                                         $\dfrac{1}{x}\left| \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) \right| \leq x^{-\delta}$. Taking limits as $x$ tends to $\infty$, we obtain the desired result ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "since this grows in a certainly nonlinear way, we can write …" Could you be more rigorous?

Comment: $x^{-\delta}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$ **if $\delta$ is a (positive) constant**.  But you have clearly stated that $\delta$ is not a constant.  So you need to provide more working if you want to claim that the limit is still $0$.

Comment: @David, since we know that for *all* $\delta$ (though variable), we have $0<\delta<1$, doesn't the limit follow ?

Comment: Please provide the working.

Comment: @Prism, we surely know that the growth of the Mertens function is not linear, don't we...?

Comment: $\delta$ depends on $x$. So write $x^{-\delta}=x^{-\delta (x)}$ with ${\delta (x)}>0.$  By itself, this is insufficient to imply that $ x^ {-\delta (x) } \to 0.$  E.g. suppose  $\delta (x)= 1/x.$  The OP's logic would imply that $f(x)/x\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ whenever $ 0<f(x)<x.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof starts to go off the rails here:

> ...and since this grows in a certainly nonlinear way, we can write $\left|\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\right|\leq x^{1-\delta}$ for every $x\geq 2$.

Okay, that's true - though it only encompasses the fact that $\left|\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\right|<x$, rather than capture any idea that that function grows "in a nonlinear way" (which is asserted without proof or even definition).  Moreover, you really ought to be writing something like:
$$\left|\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\right|\leq x^{1-\delta(x)}$$
since $\delta$ is dependent on $x$. But then dividing by $x$ gives
$$\frac{1}x\left|\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\right|\leq x^{-\delta(x)}$$
and taking limits as $x$ goes to infinity gives
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}x\left|\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\right|\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{-\delta(x)}$$
but exactly what the right hand side is depends on the function $\delta$. For instance, if $\delta(x)$ equaled $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ then the left hand converges to $\frac{1}{e}$, which is decidedly positive, contrasting with your proof, where you take this limit to be $0$.

Moreover, one might note that this proof has used nothing about the prime numbers - if I replaced the Mobius function with a function $\mu(n)$ defined to equal $1$ when $n$ is even and $0$ otherwise, then nothing in your proof breaks, but it claims that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}x\left|\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\right|=0$
which is obviously false.

Comment: Thank you @Milo, i now see where the gap is...

Comment: @MiloBrandt, however, on your example defining $\mu(n)$ to be $1$ when $n$ is even and $0$ otherwise, it seems to me that, $\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)$ grows in a *linear way*, since we have $\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) = \frac{x}{2}$ when $x$ is even and $\frac{1}{2}(x-1)$ when $x$ is odd.

Comment: @User1 Fair enough - I took "a linear way" to merely mean that you could find $\delta$ such that the sum is less than $x^{1-\delta(x)}$ (which is true, and suffices for the rest of the proof). The trouble is that the natural meaning of saying a function grows in "less than" a linear way would be that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=0$. Naturally, we can't assume that in your proof, since that's what we're supposed to prove.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Good answer. A small comment regarding the "Okey thats true". Yes it happens to be true, but OPs argument for it "since this grows in a certainly nonlinear way we have" is not a valid mathematical argument. One have to use some of the properties of $\mu(n)$ to prove this - not just state this.

Comment: @Winther Good point; it somehow slipped past me that that was problematic. I edited in a comment to this effect.

Comment: @Winther & Milo, by the non-deterministic nature of $\mu(n)$, i would say it's surely trivial that the summation grows  in a nonlinear way.

Comment: @User1 I don't know what in a "certain non-linear way" really means. You have not defined what you mean by it. When making a mathematical argument one has to be really precise.